# Formatting Cells in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I am trying to join tables together and need the PLSS to line up correctly.  In my table with geometries I have "CO060020N0650W0SN330" in a field.  I want to make a new column and make it say 2N65W33 so I can join a table.  Is there a formula I can use in the Field Calculator to get this result?

Comment: Is the current format fixed in length and with all the subfields fixed-length as well? If so it should be easy enough to use Python [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation) to pick out the required elements.

Comment: Are there other fields in the data? Usually PLSS has a field for Township, a field for Range, and a field for Section.

Comment: If so, then you could just concatenate the field using those 3 components of PLSS

Answer (score 1):

Open your field calculator for your "PLSS" field and plug these in and run them one at a time in the order I have them here. Select "python" for parser and "string" for type and just copy and paste the first one in and hit "ok", then "clear",  and then repeat for steps 2 and 3. I am sure there is a quicker, less hamfisted way to do this utilizing the code block but this will work too. You will need to change the "!yourfieldname!" to reflect what your field name actually is. Be sure to be in an edit session so you can undo any edits you don't want/need/like.

!yourfieldname!.replace('0','')
!yourfieldname![3:]
!yourfieldname!.replace('SN','')

Comment: While this does work, (it can actually be shortened to `x.replace("0","")[3:].replace("SN","")`), it would fail if not all values are the same length or if the 0s are a different numeral.

Comment: @Paul Yep...like i said, it's hamfisted but a starting point for a possible learning experience. I gave you an upvote for cleaning up that mess of mine!

Comment: That does work, but if I have a section 20, it turns it to section 2.  Am I out of luck with that?  Could I just use the !yourfieldname![3:] and adjust the numbers?

Comment: @joebob Rather than tack on extra requirements/clarifications in Comments you can edit your Question to revise it.